# How to calculate the mean of two columns with several NA's in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

i tried this already to calculate the mean of two columns:

```
df_income <- df_income %>% mutate(log_income = rowMeans(df_income_[,7,8], na.rm=TRUE))
```

But there are some cases where both  column 7 and 8 having NA's. what can i do to get a new column with the average from column 7 and 8 and for all the rows, where bothcolumns are NA, the resulat in the new column should be NA as well?

```
wave_1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                  income_wave_1=c(100, 100, 50, NA, 60, 100),
                  income_wave_2=c(NA, 120, 60,  NA, 100, 100))

 wave_final <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                  average=c(100, 110, 55, NA, 80, 100)
```

Comment: You can use `wave_1 %>% mutate(average=rowMeans(across(starts_with("income_wave")), na.rm=T))`

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  ID=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  income_wave_1=c(100, 100, 50, NA, 60, 100),
  income_wave_2=c(NA, 120, 60,  NA, 100, 100)
)

# with rowwise and c_across
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(mn = mean(c_across(c(income_wave_1, income_wave_2)), na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      ID income_wave_1 income_wave_2    mn
#>   <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1           100            NA   100
#> 2     2           100           120   110
#> 3     3            50            60    55
#> 4     4            NA            NA   NaN
#> 5     5            60           100    80
#> 6     6           100           100   100

# with apply
df %>% 
  mutate(mn = apply(cbind(income_wave_1, income_wave_2), 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE))
#>   ID income_wave_1 income_wave_2  mn
#> 1  1           100            NA 100
#> 2  2           100           120 110
#> 3  3            50            60  55
#> 4  4            NA            NA NaN
#> 5  5            60           100  80
#> 6  6           100           100 100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: i made a more precise description in my question. think should be mutate

Comment: You're right!  I changed the answer.